# Cannot read property '_id' of null (while making a post request)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

at C:\Users\Deepak\Desktop\mern-ecommerce\mern-back-end\src\controller\cart.js:75:44

I am getting this error in controllers while making a post request.

Here is my code:

Controllers (Cart.js)

```
exports.getCartItems = (req, res) => {

    Cart.findOne({ user: req.user._id })
        .populate("cartItems.product", " _id name price productPictures")
        .exec((error, cart) => {
            if (error) return res.status(400).json({ error });
            if (cart) {
                let cartItems = {};
                cart.cartItems.forEach((item, index) => {
                    cartItems[item.product._id.toString()] = {
                        _id: item.product._id.toString(),
                        name: item.product.name,
                        img: item.product.productPictures[0].img,
                        price: item.product.price,
                        qty: item.quantity,
                    };
                });
                res.status(200).json({ cartItems });
            }
        });
};
```

Routes (Cart.js)

```
router.post('/user/getCartItems', requireSignin, userMiddleware, getCartItems);
```

Models (Cart.js)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const cartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
    cartItems: [
        {
            product: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Products', required: true },
            quantity: { type: Number, default: 1 }
        }
    ]

}, {timestamps: true});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Cart', cartSchema);
```

Comment: Check if item.product._id exists before adding it.

Comment: @Grumpy Already checked it's still null

Comment: @deepakrandhawa, could you try to check these 2 places and log them, from the error given, it seems like either "req.user" or "item.product" is null